# git show not working in BASH script

Tags: git, bash

I'm trying to write a small script which will streamline checking version changes between latex files.  In the script, I'm using `git show` to pull the specified version of the file, but I'm running into issues.

Here's my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# A cl interface to compare changes between git versions of a latex doc

# Select tex file to examine
tex1=$(ls *.tex| slmenu -p "Select a tex file: ")

## Select branch
branches=$(git branch | cut -c3-)"\nHEAD"
branch=$(echo $branches | slmenu -p "Select the branch to compare to:")

# Select how many steps ago
echo "How far back? (see git reflog)"
read steps

treeish=$(echo $branch'~'$steps":'"$tex1"'")

echo "Will compare to this branch position:"
echo $treeish

git show $treeish > temp.tex
```

The file I'm testing on has white space characters.  When running the code here's the full output along with the error:

```
  Select a tex file:     SMART Reporting Tutorials.tex    SMART Reporting Tutorials.tex  
  Select the branch to compare to:    HEAD      HEAD  
How far back? (see git reflog)
1
Will compare to this branch position:
HEAD~1:'SMART Reporting Tutorials.tex'
fatal: Path ''SMART' does not exist in 'HEAD~1'
```

The error happens at line 21 when trying to run `git show $treeish > temp.tex`

However, if I copy the results of the echo,
`HEAD~1:'SMART Reporting Tutorials.tex'`, and manually write it into the terminal with git show:

```
git show HEAD:'SMART Reporting Tutorials.tex'
```

I see it works just fine.  So I guess my question is... Why does this fail in my BASH script, but works fine when I enter it into the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to quote $treeish to prevent interpretation of space characters. Your last line would become:

```
git show "$treeish" > temp.tex
```

Comment: Wonderful!!  This fixed it!

Comment: For elaboration on this... The answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable) gives a good explanation on this.